# pm2 operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, pm2

I don't know why but this isn't working. I've tried looking up online but it didn't give me what I need

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Enjuu>pm2 start index.js
fs.js:651
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Admin\.pm2\pm2.log'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:651:18)
at module.exports.Client.launchDaemon (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:219:14)
at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:103:10
at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:307:14
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Basically, ANY command I try to use with `pm2` it just throws ^ that error, and I'm using the latest(probably since I updated it like 20 mins ago) version of pm2.

Comment: looks like a permission issue. You must be starting pm2 as a wrong user . Looks at [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a permission issue. You must be starting pm2 as a wrong user . Looks at [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/487)

Comment: Great! @amNOOBok  If the above post helped, you can accept it as answer. If not, please write down on how you solved it so that other people can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

This is a **`permission error`** and you can fix it by running your terminal as

```
Run as administrator
```

where you're **`performing pm2`**

Comment: Hi, there is an already accepted answer, with this guidance